# The purpose of using generic methods where generic is some base class

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, generic-programming

Is there any purpose of using generic methods where T generic is base class? For example

```
class A: BaseClass
{
}

class B : BaseClass
{
}

class C
{
    public T test<T> (T aa) where T : BaseClass
    {
    
    }
}
```

why do not just write in this way?

```
class C
{
    public BaseClass test (BaseClass aa)
    {
    
    }
}
```

What gives us generic in this situation?

Comment: So you can do `someA = test(someA);` instead of `someA = (A)test(someA);` basically you'll get the type back that you put in.

Comment: `C.test(a).MethodDefinedOnlyOnA()` compiles with a constraint, but not if the return type is just `BaseClass`. Of course you can cast, but that's what the constraint makes unnecessary.

Comment: With the non generic version you know that it is an instance of `BaseClass` but nothing else. With the generic version you keep information of what it actually is (and due to the constraint you have to additional information that it is also a `BaseClass`). This can really matter if you pass it on to other generic methods (in libraries etc). Consider this small example where you see both ways have different outputs when we serialize the object to json: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gq0iBx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice how your method *returns* an instance of `T`.

Using generics, this is valid:

```
A input = new A();
A output = c.test(input);
```

If we try and do the same with the version which just uses `BaseClass`:

```
A input = new A();
A output = c.test(input); // Error: can not assign instance of 'BaseClass' to 'A'
```

This is, obviously, because `test` returns an instance of `BaseClass`. Instead we have to write:

```
A input = new A();
A output = (A)c.test(input);
```

... and we don't have any compile-time guarantees that `test` actually returns an instance of `A` in this case, and not an instance of `B`.

Comment: I think you meant `c.test(input)` or `A a = new A();`

Answer (score 4):

Your (non-generic) variant is returning an object of type BaseClass while the generic variant is returning an object of whatever T is (i.e. A or B or BaseClass).